# Reading Log files by pattern to retrieve fields. Log written by Log4J. Is any parser available?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a log file written by an application continuously. The application uses log4j for logging.
I cannot change the log4j configuration of the application.

Is there any java parser that can read the logs written by the application/log4j, and based on the same pattern log4j is configured in the application, can the fields from the logs be retrieved ?

Is there a way or a java parser ?

TQ,
Mahesh

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a way. You can use logstash to parse your log files in the fields you need. As you have not included a sample of you log format I'll show you an example how logstash works with a log like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] "GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3891 "http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```

Now, logstash can take this as an input and parse it into fields like:

```
{
    "message" => "127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] \"GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1\" 200 3891 \"http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0\"",
 "@timestamp" => "2013-12-11T08:01:45.000Z",
   "@version" => "1",
       "host" => "cadenza",
   "clientip" => "127.0.0.1",
      "ident" => "-",
       "auth" => "-",
  "timestamp" => "11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800",
       "verb" => "GET",
    "request" => "/xampp/status.php",
"httpversion" => "1.1",
   "response" => "200",
      "bytes" => "3891",
   "referrer" => "\"http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php\"",
      "agent" => "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0\""
}
```

You can save this output into a file or index it using elasticsearch for searching and visualize the data using Kibana.

Logstash uses a grok filter to parse the log into fields and eben if you log looks nothing like this, you can use the grok filter to parse the log into the fields you need. 
Grok uses regular expressions to find patterns in the log so you can write your own regular expressions to suit your need or you can use any of 140 something existing patterns to match timestamps, IP addresses, log4j debug levels etc.
All you need to do is make a configuration file that logstash loads on runtime,
something like this:

```
input {
       file {path => "path/to/logfile" } 
}

filter {
       grok {
             match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
       }

}



output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Here %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} is a pre-written regular expression which matches apache server logs. You can look through the available patterns or create your own. Logstash, elasticsearch and kibana are opensource.

You can look into:[how to install and use logstash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Is this better? @MattClark